# django 1.6.1 raw_id_fields open a 'change' popup instead of 'select' popup

Tags: javascript, django, caching

After updating to 1.6.1, using the magnifying glass provided by the default implementation of `raw_id_fields` in the admin panel shows a popup containing a change list, rather than a select list. Clicking on an item shows a change form rather than selecting the item, closing the window and returning the pk for the box in the admin page.

`RelatedObjectLookup.js` seems to have two versions of this line:

`href = triggeringLink.href + '&_popup=1';`
This one works, and shows up in firefox, and in my local environment.

`href = triggeringLink.href + '&_pop=1';`
This one shows up in Chrome, and shows the change form (assuming because it's looking for 'popup')

Is this a caching problem? If so, how do I clear whatever cache this is in? I've already set the cache version in the django settings up, which seemed to refresh other pieces of the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time for a break. It was just the browser cache.

Comment: Is there any way to force a cache refresh?

Comment: In the browser? Usually cmd+shift+r does it, otherwise it's in the preferences you can tell it to dump everything.

If you're talking about in django, you can set up a version in your settings file, then use it where you import css or other files that you want to be able to force a cache on your users' browsers. Like so, then just increment the version and the browser will see it like a new file and load it fresh:
`<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}events/css/detail.less?v={{settings.VERSION_NO}}" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">`

Answer (score 1):

Another situation in which you may face this problem is if you recently updated Django and forgot to perform the recollection of static files.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will copy again all your static admin files (and your own application static files) in your STATIC_ROOT directory and thus update the admin javascripts that are used in this case.

A browser cache refresh is then also required.